# Using Exchange managed api (EWS) to monitor mailbox attachments

Tags: exchange-server, ews-managed-api

I plan on creating a windows service that will monitor an exchange mailbox for mails with particular subject.  The attachments from such emails need to be stored in a specific folder on the network share.  I believe I can achieve this using Exchange Web Services Managed API (using Exchange 2007 SP1).

If you have experience with this, please share some samples or links other than the MSDN link below that can give me a jump start.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633696%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Comment: any suggestions, please?

Comment: @Pratick Kothari Have you tried asking this question on serverfault? I think you'll have more luck on that site.

Comment: Are you trying to save the attachments to a folder? Or are you trying to move the emails?

Comment: I want to save the attachment to a folder by subject of the email.

Comment: You can provide more detail for a more comprehensive example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets say these mails are coming into your Inbox on X mailbox. You create a subscription to that folder like so

```
PullSubscription subscription = 
SomeExchangeService.SubscribeToPullNotifications(
new FolderId[]{ WellKnownFolderName.Inbox },1440,"",EventType.Created);
Subscriptions.Add(subscription);
```

Now you have to set a timer and check the pull notifs

```
static void Exchanger_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {    
        foreach (var pullSubscription in Subscriptions)
        {
            foreach (var itemEvent in pullSubscription.GetEvents().ItemEvents)
            {
                Item item = Item.Bind(SomeExchangeService, itemEvent.ItemId);
                if (item.Subject == someString)
                {
                  //  item.Attachments do something
                  //  As in read it as a stream and write it 
                  //  to a file according to mime type and file extension
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

I hope this helps...

**UPDATE Due to email request**

```
public static List<PullSubscriptionpublic static List<PullSubscription> Subscriptions = new List<PullSubscription>();> Subscriptions = new List<PullSubscription>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a search folder to screen the messages. You will only need to look for, and process, messages in the search folder.

Comment: This would lead to polling the server at an interval given that you can not subscribe to searchfolders in Exchange 2007 sp1 EWS managed api.